# Java: Calibrating x and y values based on calibration values

Tags: java, android

I have the following code for calculating mouse x and y positions from on a gyroscope's azimuth (movement on the y axis) and the pitch.

```
        float rawx = Float.parseFloat(values[1]);
        float rawy = Float.parseFloat(values[2]);
```

I have a calibration method:

```
        float calx;
        float caly;
        public void calibrate(){
        calx = rawx;
        caly = rawy;
        }
        public void calculate(){
        // calculate calibrated values of x and y
        }
```

My question is: how would I compute the calibrated x and y values based on the calibration values calx, caly, and the raw values rawx, rawy?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "calibration". Given that you only have a single value for each axis, `calx` and `caly`, I can only imagine that these represent offsets: just subtract them from `rawx` and `rawy` respectively to get your "calibrated" positions.

Comment: That's the right idea, but the values can be negative or positive. I'm unsure how to go about negative values.

Comment: Why can't you subtract a negative value in exactly the same way as you'd subtract a positive value?